# Intuition behind Vacuous proofs

Tags: logic, intuition

My book says we can quickly prove the conditional statement $P \implies Q $ when we know $P $ is false. This much I'm fine with as I can show it with a truth table. But then I'm asked to, using vacuous proofs, prove $P (0)$ is true, given if $n > 1$, then $n^{2}$ > $n $. How can $P (0)$ be true? 0 is not greater than 1. Or is there some other piece to vacuous proofs that I'm overlooking?

Comment: If $(n>1)$ then $(n^2)$. Let $n=0$ and you see $(n=0<1) \Longrightarrow \neg (n>1)$, that is, our "$P$" is false. Hence vacuously true.

Comment: If $n>1$ then $n^2$ *what*?  $n^2$ does not have a truth value.

Comment: My error, it has been edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like $P(n)$ is supposed to be the statement:

> $n>1\implies n^2>n$.

When $n\le1,$ we have that $n>1$ is *false*. So, for example, $P(0)$ is true.

Comment: I see, it makes more sense that $P(n)$ is the entire statement. When the hypothesis is false, despite what the conclusion may be, the statement is true which would then make the proposition, $P(0)$ vacuously true, correct?

Comment: Absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your instructor wants.

"Whenever $0 > 1$ then $0^2 > 0$"

Well, this is vacuously true because $0$ is *never* greater than one.

Or maybe s/he wants this "Prove $P(n) = (n > 1 \implies n^2 > n)$".  In which case, you'd say "If $n \le 1$, this is vacuously true and we don't need to show anything; if n > 1 then ...

Or, least likely, s/he wants.

If $0 > 1$ then $0^2 = 0*0 > 1*0 = 0$.  Which *would* be true if 0 > 1.  But I think s/he just wants the second interpretation.